# Nginx cache EXPIRED and HIT requests are having difference of 5 bytes in response size

Tags: nginx, caching

I am trying to identify the response content length difference when nginx cache HIT vs EXPIRED. On hit I am getting 2070 bytes while on MISS/EXPIRED I am getting 2075 bytes in access log where I have printed $body_bytes_sent.

I am using gzip encoding and Tomcat as server behind nginx.

```
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "x.x.x.x"); // IP masked
      conn.setRequestProperty("Postman-Token", "bafd1fda-7aca-4757-aef8-b2a78ff8ea02,5149660d-3505-4df4-b743-6e3d48daffa5");
      conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0");
      conn.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
      conn.setRequestProperty("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

header: {Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], X-Cache-Status=[MISS], Server=[nginx/1.14.0], X-Request-Id=[4946d04e-b3ce-4868-b822-99aee71ea275], X-Served-By=[xxserverxx], Content-Encoding=[gzip], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Date=[Thu, 06 Jun 2019 09:02:44 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

header: {Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], X-Cache-Status=[HIT], Server=[nginx/1.14.0], X-Request-Id=[d36ae47c-a7a6-4c82-98e2-69f5ccf110f6], X-Served-By=[xxserverxx], Content-Encoding=[gzip], Connection=[keep-alive], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Date=[Thu, 06 Jun 2019 10:19:19 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}